# sharing session between different browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in asp.net and C# .

I have an application where user logs in to enter the application,if a user opens the application in a browser and logs in,and if user opens the application in some other browser in the **same system** they should be logged in as well.The same should happen within **the same browser in different tabs and also in the different instance of same browser** in which user was Previously logged in.please give me Your suggesions.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, as stated above, that you can't share Sessions between 2 different browsers as each browser will necessarily start a new session.

If you want a way to allow the user to log in once and stay signed in even if he opens a different browser, then you would have to rely on his IP address since this is the ONLY indicator that the user that logged in Chrome 2 secs ago, **may be** the same user that's logging in from Firefox now. This is just to give you an example but this is **obviously flawed** because different users behind the same gateway will all have the same IP.

What you want to do would work only if the application you develop is inside an Intranet and you know for sure that every user will have a unique internal IP address but then the whole point of authenticating users may be achieved through more efficient ways, like Integrated Windows Auth, etc.

Comment: +1, Side note: it is somewhat easy for client side trusted code to share the same session between browser - one just need to get cookies from HTTP response and stick them into another browser... Clearly not possible with server side or browser's JavaScript code.

Comment: One more: cookie-less session (with session ID in the Url) can obviously share the same session ID between different browsers if using the same URL... (safety/usability is up for site owner).

Answer (score 5):

You **can't share session between multiple browsers**.

But **session between multiple tabs** of a same browser instance is already **shared**.

Comment: Each browser has its own memory and they can't access each other memory so you can't do that.

Comment: Use state server or sqlserver mode for session instead of inproc

Comment: @dev and how is that supposed to allow the user to "share" sessions as he wants?

Comment: @Dev, thats a mechanism for managing session, By doing that, one browsers won't be able to access the session of the other browsers. For example, Chrome can't access the session of IE

Comment: @Habib Thanks :) I was supposed to be wrong by understanding the session modes.

Comment: @Dev the link you posted does not answer the user's question. He's referring to 2 different browsers, not 2 instances of the same browser...

Comment: OK guys, I step back and delete that link :)

Answer (score 2):

You can share session between two browsers ,we have implemented such a project couple of years back .

The technique used was to write a custom browser which instead of storing cookies in local machine stored it in a in a public server 
so that when one guy logs in the cookie & other local data associated with the session is shared with the server and thus with all browser instances ,browsers instances cookie is modified to match with the server details ,So it behaves as if the session is shared .
some websites have issue with using different ip that could be solved by using a common proxy server .

but if you can't use custom browsers then it will be difficult but could still try with plugins that follow the above mentioned method 
Hope this helps